# How to center HTML elements vertically

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center vertically two arrows. One on the left and one on the right. The end goal is to try to make a slider of HTML and javascript content as a learning tool. I can't seem to get the arrows to center vertically. Below is the code I'm using. I've tried the vertical-align and top: 50% but that does not seem to work. Thank you.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}
#slide1 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide2 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide3 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide4 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide5 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#right-button {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 2px;
  font-size: 5em;
}
#left-button {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<h3>Presentation Slider</h3>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-button"><strong>&lt;</strong>
  </div>
  <!--
 <div id="slide1"></div>
 <div id="slide2"></div>
 <div id="slide3"></div>
 <div id="slide4"></div>
 <div id="slide5"></div>
 -->
  <div id="right-button"><strong>&gt;</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know about `class`es? Rather than adding the same CSS to each and every ID you can use a `class`. Alternatively you can combine all the selectors that have the same CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can make it like this:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
#slide1 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide2 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide3 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide4 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide5 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#right-button {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 2px;
  font-size: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#left-button {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  font-size: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h3>Presentation Slider</h3>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-button"><strong>&lt;</strong>
  </div>
  <!--
        <div id="slide1"></div>
        <div id="slide2"></div>
        <div id="slide3"></div>
        <div id="slide4"></div>
        <div id="slide5"></div>
        -->
  <div id="right-button"><strong>&gt;</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - flexbox is the easiest way now

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: #eee;
  display:flex;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h3>Presentation Slider</h3>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left-button"><strong>&lt;</strong></div>
        <!--
        <div id="slide1"></div>
        <div id="slide2"></div>
        <div id="slide3"></div>
        <div id="slide4"></div>
        <div id="slide5"></div>
        -->
        <div id="right-button"><strong>&gt;</strong></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This will probably mess up the positioning of his slides though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#wrapper{
  position:relative;
}

#left-button, #right-button{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
}

#left-button{
  left : 0;
}

#left-button{
  right : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper{
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: black;
  position:relative;
}
#slide1{
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
#slide2{
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
#slide3{
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
#slide4{
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
#slide5{
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
#right-button{
    color: white;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 2px;
    font-size: 5em;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:0;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
#left-button{
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2px;
    font-size: 5em;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

```html
<h3>Presentation Slider</h3>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left-button"><strong>&lt;</strong></div>
        <!--
        <div id="slide1"></div>
        <div id="slide2"></div>
        <div id="slide3"></div>
        <div id="slide4"></div>
        <div id="slide5"></div>
        -->
        <div id="right-button"><strong>&gt;</strong></div>
    </div>
```

I have used relative and absolute positioning method to center vertically two arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Your style sheet is not properly connected. Move it to the tag `<head>`
[image]

Comment: Same is true for meta and title. Still this is no answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: Exactly! And there is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
#right-button,
#left-button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -25px; /* height/2 */
}
#right-button{
    color: white;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 2px;
    font-size: 5em;
    right: 0;
}
#left-button{
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2px;
    font-size: 5em;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Play with `translate`, the cool thing of this trick is you don't care of the dimensions of the `#wrapper` because it will take always the center :)

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jjLpf584/ :)

```
#wrapper{
   position: relative;
}

#left-button {
 position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
#right-button {
 position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that using flex-box concept

add the following css to your code

```
#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

```css
#wrapper{
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: black;
}
#slide1{
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
#slide2{
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
#slide3{
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
#slide4{
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
#slide5{
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
#right-button{
    color: white;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 2px;
    font-size: 5em;
}
#left-button{
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2px;
    font-size: 5em;
}

#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/stylesheet.css">
<head>
  <style>
  </style>

  <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h3>Presentation Slider</h3>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left-button"><strong>&lt;</strong></div>
        <!--
        <div id="slide1"></div>
        <div id="slide2"></div>
        <div id="slide3"></div>
        <div id="slide4"></div>
        <div id="slide5"></div>
        -->
        <div id="right-button"><strong>&gt;</strong></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid #dedede;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;  
}

.slide.active {
  display: block;
}

#left-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

#right-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <h3>Presentation Slider</h3>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-button"><strong>&lt;</strong></div>

  <div id="slide1" class="slide active">Slide 1 content</div>
  <div id="slide2" class="slide">Slide 2 content</div>
  <div id="slide3" class="slide">Slide 3 content</div>
  <div id="slide4" class="slide">Slide 4 content</div>
  <div id="slide5" class="slide">Slide 5 content</div>

  <div id="right-button"><strong>&gt;</strong></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uL03e3wt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this css code

```
#right-button {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 45%;
    right:10px;
}

#left-button {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 45%;
    left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just position the `wrapper` with `relative` and `button` with `absolute` and one button to left and another to right.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
#slide1 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide2 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide3 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide4 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide5 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
}
#right-button {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 2px;
  font-size: 5em;
  right: 0;
}
#left-button {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  font-size: 5em;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Presentation Slider</h3>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-button" class="arrow">
     <strong>&lt;</strong>
  </div>
  <!--
 <div id="slide1"></div>
 <div id="slide2"></div>
 <div id="slide3"></div>
 <div id="slide4"></div>
 <div id="slide5"></div>
 -->
  <div id="right-button" class="arrow">
    <strong>&gt;</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to tweak your css a bit for left and right button

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}
#slide1 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide2 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide3 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide4 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#slide5 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}
#right-button {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 2px;
  font-size: 5em;
  position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
}
#left-button {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  font-size: 5em;
  position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h3>Presentation Slider</h3>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-button"><strong>&lt;</strong>
  </div>
  <!--
 <div id="slide1"></div>
 <div id="slide2"></div>
 <div id="slide3"></div>
 <div id="slide4"></div>
 <div id="slide5"></div>
 -->
  <div id="right-button"><strong>&gt;</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do this.

1. flex
2. position absolute

this one is using flex

```css
div{
background:#ccc;
color:#fff;
width:100%;
height:200px;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div>

this is center
  
</div>
```

and this one is using position

```css
.parent{
background:#000;
width:100%;
height:400px;
position:relative}

.child{
background:#ccc;
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

<div class="child"> this is center </div>
  
</div>
```

which one suit you? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}
#right-button {
  color: white;
  font-size: 5em;
}
#left-button {
  color: white;
  font-size: 5em;
}
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: gray;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
.div-left {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  width: 10%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.div-middle{
  display: flex;
  text-align:center;
  width: 90%;
  height:400px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.div-right{
  width: 10%;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3>Presentation Slider</h3>
<div id="wrapper" class="main-container">
    <div id="left-button" class="div-left"><strong>&lt;</strong></div>
    <div class="div-middle">This is the div with slides</div>
    <!--
    <div id="slide1"></div>
    <div id="slide2"></div>
    <div id="slide3"></div>
    <div id="slide4"></div>
    <div id="slide5"></div>
    -->
    <div id="right-button" class="div-right"><strong>&gt;</strong></div>
</div>
```